# How can I automate these formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Hello,
I need to automate these formula.

Wheat 2 USA *minus* wheat 1 USA, Wheat 2 Brazil *minus* wheat 1 Brazil, Wheat 2 Canada *minus* wheat 1 Canada, Wheat 2 Argentina *minus* wheat 1 Argentina and so on for every product and taking into account corresponding regions and week numbers.

Barley 2 USA *minus* barley 1 USA, Barley 2 Brazil *minus* barley 1 Brazil, Barley 2 Canada *minus* barley 1 Canada ...

A formula should work in such a way that when I populate it, it understands the logic and make a calculation.

Comment: What have you tried, and what was the result?

Comment: Well, for my experience with formulas this logic is quite difficult to realize. But I though of using somehow "index and match" ....

Comment: pivot table maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LOOKUP` to find previous value of current product:

```
=IFERROR(C2-LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:A1=A2),$C$1:C1),"")
```

or so if the `Input number` column matters:

```
=IFERROR(C2-LOOKUP(2,1/(($A$1:A1=A2)*($B$1:B1=(B2-1))),$C$1:C1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank the this formula wotk fow this table but I am not able to apply it to my real table. My real table has also regions of a country. I will update my question....

Comment: now I need to subtrack quantity taking into account regions also. For example, Wheat-2-USA - Wheat-1-USA and so on.

Comment: Add a new condition ```($D$1:D1=D2)``` to ```1/(($A$1:A1=A2)*...```

Answer (score 1):

First: I like @basic's solution much better! I keep forgetting that `=LOOKUP(LargerThanAll,Nums,Values)` returns the value for the highest num!

That said, here's another way:

First, put your cursor on the top line and **Insert - Table**, making sure you check the "My table has headers" checkbox in the dialog box that appears.

Now, in addition to having it formatted, there are formula benefits.

Keeping with your example where the B2 = "Product",

- Change F2 to "Product|Number" to create a new column
- Change F3 to `=[@Product]&"|"&[@[Input Number]]` (Because you're using tables, you can use column names rather than cell references, [@ColumnName] is the column value for the current row, it will use that formula for the entire column, and the formula is stored *once* instead of once per row!)
- Change G2 to "PrevRow"
- Change G3 to `=MATCH([@Product]&"|"&([@[Input Number]]-1),[Product|Number],0)` (you now have the table row number for the previous value
- Change E3 to `=IF(ISNUMBER([@PrevRow]),[@Quantity]-INDEX([Quantity],[@PrevRow]),"")`
- Hide columns F and G. (Or fold their functionality into your Volume's formula so your volume formula doesn't need them and delete them.)

[image: Image of solution]